# Pygame Collision without Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm a relatively new python developer, and I stumbled across a problem. I could not get the pygame.sprite.collide_rect() function to work, and I couldnt find any solutions on the web. here's my code:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

pygame.display.set_caption('Doge Adventures')

gameexit = False

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

move_x = 300
move_y = 300

def checkCollision(sprite1, sprite2):
    col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite1,sprite2)
    if col == True:
        sys.exit()

while not gameexit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameexit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            move_x -= 15 
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            move_x += 15
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            move_y -= 15
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            move_y += 15

gameDisplay.fill(white)

b1 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [move_x, move_y, 40, 40])
b2 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [450 , 450, 50, 50])

b1,b2

checkCollision(b1,b2)

pygame.QUIT()
quit()
```

and the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DEREK\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Doge           Adventures\Game.py", line 45, in <module>
    checkCollision(b1,b2)
  File "C:\Users\DEREK\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Doge     Adventures\Game.py", line 19, in checkCollision
    col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite1,sprite2)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1147, in     collide_rect
    return left.rect.colliderect(right.rect)
 AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

Btw, I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Please also note that I have limited knowledge of python classes/objects, so if you can, please don't include classes in the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The `pygame.sprite.colliderect` method is for checking collisions between **sprites**, not rectangles as you are using. Sprites are instances of the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class. What you are trying to detect collisions between are rectangles, which have there own collision detection method: `b1.colliderect(b2)`. Rectangles are not sprites and sprites are not rectangles.